# Which driver for "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650" in a laptop?

Tags: drivers, windows-vista, ati-mobility-radeon

We have some HP laptops here that comes equipped with a video card that identifies itself as "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650", like [this one](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Mobility-Radeon-HD-3650.8839.0.html).

However, which drivers do we choose? As far as we can tell, HD 3650 is desktop cards, or at least there are no drivers listed for that series with "Mobility" in their name.

If I pick the following on the [ATI Driver Download page](http://www.amd.com/se/Pages/AMDHomePage.aspx):

- Graphics
- Windows Vista 32-bit Edition
- Mobility Radeon

Then the dropdown for the card model contains X300, X600, X700, X800, X1300, X1400, X1600, X1800, 9600, 9700 and 9800 models, but no "HD" nor "36xx series".

However, if I change to just "Radeon" for the last selection there, I can find a "Radeon HD 3600 Series" model in the list.

Also, if I pick "Windows 7" as the operating system, I can find a "Mobility Radeon HD 3000 series" card, but no 3600.

So, which one to pick?

The main reason I ask is that they all seem to have some kind of problem installing, so neither seems to be the right one (they all crash with "Catalyst Install Manager has stopped working".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer can be found at http://www.driverheaven.net/modtool.php .

OK, I'll explain further. ATi typically does not release updated laptop drivers. The monthly updates are for desktops. So, you have to get your laptop video drivers from your laptop vendor, which updates them less than occasionally.

So, the folks at driver heaven take ATi's latest releases and hack them for laptop users.

Comment: We're trying this now, seems much more promising than everything else we've read and tried. I'll come back with info when we're done.

Comment: Keep us updated, I'm sure lots of laptop 3650 users will find this page.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you would use the 3000 series drivers. For the record, when they say '3000 series', that means it pretty much covers all the models from 3000 to 3999. Not that they have a 3999 model but you get the point. It's basically like saying 3xxx series.

When you run the install the software might say that your model is not found, but you can select the HAVE DISK option and manually pick from the list using the INF in your ATI driver folder.

Some would say this is not recommended but in my experience, I haven't had any issues yet.

-maj

Answer (score 0):

I am aware this is a huge necropost, but I had very similar problem today, and the situation has changed in last 2 years. Maybe someone will find this useful.

Mobility Modder seems to be abandoned for long time, so in case you still use Win XP and want to update your Mobility Radeon drivers, [this thread](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/windows-xp-radeon-display-drivers/205454-ati-radeon-mobility-modded-catalyst-drivers-windows-xp-32-bit-updated.html) might be valuable.

The guy who is thread's author removed the links to his modded driver packages because of poor response from people, so I will not paste links here, but you can take advantage of the fact that [nothing can be erased from internet so easily](http://www.searchengineshowdown.com/others/archive.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the updated drivers for Mobility Radeon HD 3xxx series [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) Mobility cards are notebook class GPU's and the update installer is called AMD Catalyst™